# How to customize the Django Users model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Currently, I have added a registration functionality to my website thanks to the `Users` model from the `django.contrib.auth.models` and I want to add a `score` field which will give by default 100 points once the user has registered. I have the following code for the user registration:

```
forms.py 

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name  = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    email      = forms.EmailField()
    score      = forms.CharField(max_length=5) # max value 99,999

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

views.py

from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form}
```

The current problem with my code is that the form displays the `points` field which shouldn't be the case and I am not sure how to indicate to Django that every time the user gets registered then the user should receive a 100 value in score. When I have used a postgresql db, I have implemented this as a default value,i.e., `score = models.IntegerField(default=100)` but this behavior doesn't work for the `Users` model from the `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` because you will get the error `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'` Any help, edit or any other contribution to this question will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You should always subclass the user model.

Comment: How would you do that? Also, is it always better to use the `Users model` rather than using another db, i.e., `postgres`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions from `@cpy24` and `@aris24` I found out the solution for customizing the `Users` models.

```
models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, score, password=None):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address.")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("User must have a username.")
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("User must have a first name.")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("User must have a last name.")

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            score = score,
      )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, score, password):

        user = self.create_user(email=self.normalize_email(email),
           username=username,
           first_name = first_name,
           last_name = last_name,
           score = score,
           password=password, 
      )

         user.is_admin = True
         user.is_staff = True
         user.is_superuser = True
         user.save(using=self._db)
         return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email        = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username     = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name   = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name    = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    score        = models.FloatField(default=100)

    # The following fields are required for every customer User model
    last_login   = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    date_joined  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' 
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'score']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

And then simply I go my `forms.py` and add the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreation

User = get_user_model()

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','username','email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Lastly, I go to the `settings.py` of the main app and add the following:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account'
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry that I can't comment, but have to tried [substituting the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)?

Whereas in your **settings.py**:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

> and I want to add a score field which will give by default

I don't think Django's default auth user will come with a `score` field, so you may have to create your own user model via extending Django's [AbstractUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) class then adding your field.